# How to query a pivot table data in MySQL (many to many relationship)

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join

I am doing a small project in which I have videogames that may belong to more than one category/genre (a videogame can belong to RPG and shooter categories). I want to be able to get all the games that belong to a specific category, let's say all RPGs videogames.
I created 3 tables: videogames, categories, game-category.

```
 1. videogames table
 --------------------------
| id | name | price | date |
|----|------|-------|------|

 2. categories table
 ---------------
| id | category | 
|----|----------|

 3. game-category table
 -----------------------
| id_game | id_category | 
|---------|-------------|
```

Given these 3 tables and their columns, if I want to get All the games that belong to ***RPG*** category, how should I formulate the query? I tried with several queries, all similar to this one below, but I got errors.

> SELECT DISTINCT videogames.name, videogames.id, categories.name, categories.id 
>   FROM videogames 
>   JOIN game-category ON videogames.id = game-category.id_game
>   JOIN game-category ON categories.id = game-category.id_category

***Is there any good resource online to fully understand SQL syntax and JOINs?***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are basically on the right path.  You are not bringing in the `categories` table and you need a filter:

```
SELECT vg.name, vg.id, c.name, c.id
FROM videogames vg JOIN
     game_category gc
     ON vg.id = gc.id_game JOIN 
     categories c
     ON c.id = gc.id_category
WHERE c.name = 'RPG';
```

Note the use of table aliases so the query is easier to write and to read.

Comment: Thank you! That was useful! My query's still not working... appearently I have a syntax error somwhere after he first JOIN. If I get rid of "JOIN game - category ON videogames.id = game - category.id_game" though, according to SQL syntax validators the statement is correct...